# how to search for text in json array

Tags: javascript, bixby, bixbystudio

Need to search JSON array for text string.

The facts/joke module in Bixby currently searches by tags rather than full text.   I want to modify the filter function to search the full text field.

At present, the filter function looks like this.

```
exports.findContentJS = findContentJS
function findContentJS (items, searchTerm) {
  var matches = items.filter(function (x) {
    if (x.tags) {
      // Filter on filter 
      var matchTag = x.tags.filter(function (y) {
        return y == searchTerm
      });
      return (matchTag != "");
    }
  });
  return matches;
}
```

I tried changing "tags" to "text".

So for a search on "Mark Twain" I get an error message like this:

> TypeError: Cannot find function filter in object A banker is a fellow who lends you his umbrella when the sun is shining and wants it back the minute it begins to rain. Source: Mark Twain

This is the corresponding object in the json file:

```
{
  tags: ["literature"],
  text: "A banker is a fellow who lends you his umbrella when the sun is shining and wants it back the minute it begins to rain. Source: Mark Twain"
}
```

So it appears to me that I need to make a likely small change in the function so that it searches both the tags & the text field in the array.

Answer (score 2):

.text isn't an array, so won't have a filter function

just use

```
exports.findContentJS = findContentJS
function findContentJS (items, searchTerm) {
    var matches = items.filter(function (x) {
        return x.includes(searchTerm);
    });
    return matches;
}
```

or,

```
exports.findContentJS = findContentJS
const findContentJS = (items, searchTerm) => items.filter(x => x.includes(searchTerm));
```

Comment: Spot on comment wise and solution but need a small tweak to make the code above work by searching on text - change `return x.includes(searchTerm)` to `return x.text.includes(searchTerm)` or even better `return x.text.toLowerCase().includes(searchTerm)`

Answer (score 1):

Try this (might get small errors, because writting this before bed time):

```
let findContent = (jsonArr, searchedItem) => {
   let arr = [];
   jsonArr.forEach(obj => {

  for(let content in obj) {
    if(content == 'text'){
      let filtered = obj[content].split(' ').filter(el => el == searchedItem);
      if(filtered){
        arr.push(obj[content]);
      }
    }
  }
return arr;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I wound up doing this which was contributed by a member of the Bixby team.

```
function findContent (items, searchTerm, searchAuthor) {
  var matches = []
  //searchTerm = searchTerm.toLowerCase()
  console.log(searchTerm)
  console.log(searchAuthor)
  ;

  for (var i = 0; i < items.length; i++) {
    if (items[i].text.includes(searchTerm)) { //change with substring or any other kind of a matching you need
        matches.push(items[i])
    } else if (items[i].tags) {
      for (var j = 0; j < items[i].tags.length; j++) {
        if (searchTerm == items[i].tags[j].toLowerCase()) {
          matches.push(items[i])
          break
        }
      }
    }
  }
  return matches
}
```